# What does "grade-B" mean here?

Tags: meaning

> ... the film had struck her as just another grade-B operetta.

I know the meaning of [operetta](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/operetta) but I don't know the meaning of grade-B here. Does it symply refer to the quality of the opperetta or refer to another thing, for example to its audiences age?

Could you please explain it to me?

The fuller text is here:

> At the time there was a film being shown in Prague which Comrade Stano
> liked to discuss, with deep emotion, calling it the pinnacle of
> Socialist Realism and a masterful reflection of Soviet life. It was
> called Cossacks from the Kuban and it featured buxom young women and
> handsome young men turning hay and harvesting wheat to the
> accompaniment of a four-part chorus of socialist work songs. Perfect
> harmony reigned in this classless paradise and one of our editors, in
> what was obviously a fit of temporary insanity, remarked that **the film
> had struck her as just another grade-B operetta.** The remark rendered
> the collective speechless. The editor was asked to conduct a
> self-critique at the next meeting and, with the help of all the
> comrades, to correct her erroneous views. She was asked to continue
> correcting them for some ten more meetings and, had it not been for
> the complete exhaustion of everyone concerned, she would still have
> been doing penance in 1968.

From: *Under a Cruel Star*: A Life in Prague 1941-1968 by  Heda Margolius Kovály

Comment: It refers to the quality:    A = the best, B = the rest

Comment: There is a category of _very_ minor celebrity called 'Z-list'  - as the New York Times says - "Aspiring models, third-tier reality show stars, impossible-to-place actors, YouTube vloggers and viral news subjects who can curry coverage just by replenishing their social media accounts with photos of their babies, their butts or both. These are people you’ve probably never heard of — or have a nagging suspicion you might have, but don’t quite know why."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It refers to quality. "B" comes after "A", so it means "not of the highest quality".

Comment: Similarly a **B-movie** and the **B-side** of a phonograph record.

Comment: Yes, but be careful here because the B-side does not have to inferior in quality to the A.  It can be of similar (or even better) quality  but not suited to the commercial ambitions of the record label.